# Trigger gitlab downstream pipeline from a upstream pipeline in a multi-project using trigger, rules and custom configuration variables

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this scenario where I want to run the trigger in build stage only when `$FLAG` variable has been set by the `.pre` stage. However, the `build` stage never runs.

How should I conditionally trigger a downstream pipeline?

```
checkArtifactPresent:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - >
      set +e;
      if curl -s -S -f $NEXUS_RAW_PICKER_REPOSITORY/${PRODUCT_FLAVOR}/${PRODUCT_FLAVOR}-${BUILD_TYPE}v${PICKER_TEMPLATE_TAG}.apk --output ${PRODUCT_FLAVOR}-${BUILD_TYPE}v${PICKER_TEMPLATE_TAG}.apk;
      then
        export FLAG= true;
      fi

buildArtifact:
  stage: build
  only:
   variables:
     - $FLAG
  trigger:
   project: dev/project_name
   strategy: depend
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of Gitlab web api for `Triggering pipelines through API`

You can make use of trigger variables. You can apply conditions and then trigger the downstream job.

Here you can find a simple example:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#making-use-of-trigger-variables

Comment: Yes, i found that, but the issue is that then the upstream pipeline does not wait for the downstream pipeline to complete. Well, I am in the process of writing a script to make the upstream pipeline to wait. I guess with the current version of gitlab there is no feature while using rules right ?